# Skrollr not calculating full browser height

Tags: jquery, skrollr

I'm assuming that's what the problem is. On IE it seems like it's getting a height that is over the real height of the body, and on Chrome it's getting smaller number.

I'm not 100% sure that this is what is happening, but it's my best guess so far.

Here is a page I'll use as an example: http://driftingcreatives.com/work/triseum/

The right hand bar has a div who's height grows as you scroll from 0% to 100% of the page. Obviously at the bottom of the page is when it should reach the second plus sign.

Here is my skrollr initialization. I did try removing forceHeigh, but to no avail.

```
if(!(/Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i).test(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera)){
    skrollr.init({
        forceHeight: false
    });
}
```

Here is the HTML element.

```
<div class="bg" data-anchor-target="body" data-top="height:0px;" data-bottom="height:348px;"></div>
```

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that if I load a page that doesn't work as intended, and I resize the browser, it fixes. Not sure if that'll help, but I figured it was worth stating.

Comment: are you still seeing this? Looks ok to me in chrome.

Comment: yeah i'm still having the same problem. some pages work, and some don't. like the div will get taller, but it'll reach the bottom before i reach the page bottom.